# How to Import file from subdirectory of ZIP file?

Tags: import, files-and-directories

I have a `"ZIP"` file that contains directories.

```
Import["arch.zip", "FileNames"]
(* {"subdir\\test.txt"} *)
```

However, `Import` errors that it cannot find the file in the subdirectory.

```
Import["arch.zip", {"subdir\\test.txt", "CSV"}]
```

> Import::noelem: The Import element "subdir\test.txt" is not present when importing as ZIP. >>

However, if I add a file at the root of the zip

```
Import["arch.zip", "FileNames"]
(* {"subdir\\test.txt", "test2.txt"} *)
```

The root file imports it without issue

```
Import["arch.zip", {"test2.txt", "CSV"}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}} *)
```

How do I import files in subdirectories of zip files?  I rather not import the entire zip as some of the files are very large and I don't need them.

I have not included a zip as I know people are squeamish about downloads.

**May be a bug:** Can anyone confirm 10.4.1 Win 7 Ent SP1

Comment: i just tried this and what you tried works fine.  Maybe a version/system issue. (10.1/windows here)

Comment: @george2079 Added version

Comment: note for test purpose you can create such a zip like this: `Export["testzip.zip",{"root.dat" -> {1},  "sub\\test.dat" -> {42}}]`  then `Import["testzip.zip", #] & /@ Import["testzip.zip"]` -> `{{{1}}, {{42}}}`

Comment: @george2079 Well, it works for small zip files but not the larger one I am trying to extract from.  May have something to do with the zip file size or the compressed file size.

Comment: Have you see `ExtractArchive`?

Comment: @yode No I haven't.  This may save me.  I'll check it when I'm next in the office.  Strange that this is not in the [Importing and Exporting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html) guide. Even though from its documentation page it should have a link there. Not in the [Compression and Archive Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CompressionAndArchiveFormats.html) guide either.

Comment: Yup.It deserve to hunt. :)

Comment: @yode This solved the problem. I was able to extract and access the file. I am sending a note to WRI that there is no intuitive way to find `ExtractArchive`.  I think it may be a documentation link bug.

Comment: @Edmund good job.